# capybara: save_and_open_page. Error - no display specified Couldn't find a suitable web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

In test file, capybara method `save_and_open_page` display error:
**Error: no display specified
Couldn't find a suitable web browser!
Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
Opening "/home/ubuntu/workspace/tmp/capybara/capybara-201604201009291019595495.html" with Firefox Web Browser  (text/html)**

```
Error: no display specified
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/ubuntu/workspace/tmp/capybara/capybara-201604201009291019595495.html'
```

**gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry-byebug'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'annotate'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


group :production do
  gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'capybara'

end
```

How can I set browser chrome?

Comment: in your `spec_helper.rb`, do you have something like `Capybara.default_driver = :webkit` ?

Comment: no, i dont have this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xdg-open` command **does not have a default browser configured** in your setup. You can verify this with:

```
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
# (probably will not print anything)
```

To set a default browser for `xdg-open`, run this:

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

If this does not help, try searching all `.desktop` files that are defined for google chrome:

```
$ locate .desktop | grep chrome
```

choose one of them and supply it to the `xdg-settings` command above (without the path, just the filename with the `.desktop` extension).

You can always test it by trying to open a link from the command line:

```
$ xdg-open http://google.com
```

See the [`xdg-settings` man page](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/xdg-settings/) for more info.

Comment: i calling in command line xdg-settings get default-web-browser, display error:
xdg-settings: unknown desktop environment

Comment: What OS is that? Do you use graphical display environment (such as X-windows)?

Comment: And what graphical desktop - gnome, unity, KDE, or something else?

Comment: Hmm, looking at your exact error again, you don't seem to be using graphical display at all - are you calling the tests from ssh / console?

Comment: So you have no graphical environment? Sorry but how would you want to use chrome then?? In that case I'd simply install one of the text-only browsers, such as `links2`.

Comment: i open my project in google chrome. I have graphical env. Sorry, dont undestand you correct

Comment: OK, sorry, for the pressure. Can you show the output of `echo $DISPLAY` ? And also `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` ? Thanks

Comment: i am worked in cloud ide cloud9. They work in ubuntu. Maybe in this problem. better i will ask support cloud9. Thank you for you help.

Comment: OK, last note: `xdg-open` recognizes automatically only a few desktops, you can see them if you look at the bottom of the `/usr/bin/xdg-open` (it's a bash script). If yours is not among them then it tries to open one of  generic browser (chrome is among them). But it tries chrome only when the `$DISPLAY` variable is set. If it is empty, then it tries `links` etc text-only browsers... This info might be useful to the support. Good luck!